How to perform ONNX model evaluation after conversion from RT-DETR
I was able to convert RT-DETR, which I trained on my own dataset in COCO format, to ONNX format, which I then need to convert to TFLite. I used TorchScript torch.onnx.export ONNX exporter to convert.
import torch
from transformers import (
    AutoImageProcessor,
    AutoModelForObjectDetection
)
        
CHECKPOINT = "/content/rt-detr-finetuned/checkpoint-9300"
DEVICE = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    
model = AutoModelForObjectDetection.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT).to(DEVICE)
processor = AutoImageProcessor.from_pretrained(CHECKPOINT) 
model.eval()
        
dummy_input = torch.randn(1, 3, 640, 640).to(DEVICE)

torch.onnx.export(
    model, 
    dummy_input, 
    "rt-detr_model.onnx",
    opset_version=17, 
    input_names=["input"],
    output_names=["output"]
)

I would need to do an evaluation of the ONNX model and calculate quality metrics, or better to say the accuracy of the model training, namely mAP50_95, mAP50 and mAP75.
Can anyone advise me a tool or a script that would work in Google Colab, with the help of which I would be able to make an evaluation and calculate the accuracy of the model after conversion?
